# How to check internet connection every xx minutes and log the result?

Tags: connection-issues, data-connection, automation

I am having issues with internet connection - only at home and only sometimes. I want to debug it so I am looking for an application that would check the internet connection every xx minutes and log the result. Does anything like that exist?

Comment: Use Tasker.. If you don't want to pay, there are alternatives..

Comment: OK. Tasker can run something. How do I get log out of it? And what would it run?

Comment: Create a profile to send GET request to reliable server periodically. Log this in a file. To stop logging, simply turn off this profile. Done!

Comment: @SachinShekhar Maybe you compile your comments into an answer?